# Moq - Reference parameter in virtual method doesn't update correctly when class is mocked

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have test that check ref parameter value from event that raised after the change. The test work fine when I create real class but when I try mocked class its fail. Simple code example:

```
[TestClass]
public class Fixture
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void CheckRealClass()
    {
        // this test passed
        var classToTest = new NumberChangerClass();
        CheckClass(classToTest);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void CheckMockedClass()
    {
        // this test failed
        var classToTest = new Mock<NumberChangerClass>() { CallBase = true };
        CheckClass(classToTest.Object);
    }

    private void CheckClass(NumberChangerClass numberChangerClass)
    {
        // Arrange
        var number = 1;
        numberChangerClass.StorageChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(2, number);
        };


        // Act
        numberChangerClass.SetValue(ref number, 2);
    }
}

public class NumberChangerClass
{
    public event EventHandler StorageChanged;

    public virtual void SetValue(ref int storage, int newValue)
    {
        storage = newValue;
        StorageChanged?.Invoke(this, null);
    }
}
```

In `CheckMockedClass` the `number` is actually changed but only after the the code exits from `SetValue` method.

I use Moq version 4.2.1409.1722 but it doesn't work also in the latest version (4.8.1).

There is a way to make `CheckMockedClass` to pass?

**UPDATE:**

I've opened issue in moq github: [link](https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/585)

short answer: there nothing that can be done about it.

more details:

> the behaviour you are observing is a direct consequence of how DynamicProxy (which Moq depends on) handles by-reference parameters during method call interception (which is documented at https://github.com/castleproject/Core/blob/master/docs/dynamicproxy-by-ref-parameters.md): Arguments are buffered in a separate location during call interception and only written back at the end of interception, that's why refparameters are updated in a delayed / deferred manner. There is unfortunately nothing that can be done about it.

I still try to find a way to get the updated number when I check `Assert.AreEqual(2, number);`

Comment: Why are you mocking the class under test?

Comment: This is only simple code. In the real case my class is much more complicated and I need to setup some methods of the class.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation

Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart)

Ended up having to make the event virtual on the concrete class as that is what Moq can work with. If how ever it was defined on an interface, it would work out of the box.

```
public class NumberChangerClass {
    public virtual event EventHandler StorageChanged;

    public virtual void SetValue(ref int storage, int newValue) {
        storage = newValue;
        StorageChanged?.Invoke(this, null);
    }
}
```

In order to mock it and raise the event.

```
delegate void SetValueCallback(ref int storage, int newValue);

[TestMethod]
public void CheckMockedClass() {
    var classToTest = new Mock<NumberChangerClass>() { CallBase = true };
    // callbacks for methods with `ref` / `out` parameters are 
    //possible but require some work (and Moq 4.8 or later):

    classToTest
        .Setup(_ => _.SetValue(ref It.Ref<int>.IsAny, It.IsAny<int>()))
        .Callback(new SetValueCallback((ref int storage, int newValue) => {
            storage = newValue;
            classToTest.Raise(_ => _.StorageChanged += null, EventArgs.Empty);
        }));
    CheckClass(classToTest.Object);
}
```

Which is actually mimicking what is done in the base method, hence my concern about mocking the class under test.

This has a code smell to it and would advise reviewing the current design of the code being tested.

Comment: In my case I can't change the event to virtual and when I try your solution the test passed because the test doesn't reach to Assert.AreEqual(2, number).